# What is the best app for controlling the time of kids spend on iPad?

Tags: ipad, applications

My kids spend way more time on ipad. I want to limit the time each child spends on iPad on a daily basis. Any apps? They yell at us for taking away the iPad.

Comment: Have you used Guided Access? In iOS 8 you can set a time limit.

Answer (score 1):

We used Guided Access (https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/ipad/ipada16d1374/ipados) to set a timer, control what buttons can be used, etc.

We can turn it on in an app so that they can't leave that app or give them free rein with a time limit. Combine with Screen Time (https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/ipad/ipadb15cb886/ipados) and you can limit per app usage as well.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few:

[ParentKit](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/parentkit-parental-controls/id600618138?mt=8) 
[Parental Timelock](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/parental-timelock-time-limit/id689577280?mt=8) 
TimeLock (I couldn't post link)

You can also restrict and block internet usage during certain days and time blocks for each device in your home that uses your wifi. You can do this through your wifi router.

Comment: - parentkit It will be good but my suggestion is, better you can take them out with you or join them to some courses or in sports rather than giving mobile